# Add Parameter Values to Query String of get request in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a Copy Data task which is obtaining data from an API

The API is a GET call to a method and requires 2 parameters

```
_token
Symbols
```

I have defined these as parameters

[image]

What is the syntax that allows me to use the values of my parameters as the values that are in the query string?  So in the screenshot above Symbols is hard coded, but I want the value to be the value of the parameters

I need a screen solution rather than code please as I am not comfortable with ADF yet and I dont know how to get to the code/ARM views

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a feature called string interpolation where expressions are wrapped in @{ ... }

[image]

Click on the Base URL field. Add Parameters. Using [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#concat) expression function,

**Example:**

```
@{Concat('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/GetRealTimeRates?',linkedService().Symbols,'=',linkedService()._token)}
```

Add first parameter:

[image]

Add second parameter:

[image]

Test connection. If you see any error, it would provide a description as to debug further.

[image]

Comment: Hi this looks great however, I get a totally useless error message - Failed to run pipeline even though test connection passes.  I have no idea how to get more information?

Comment: Please update the error message you see or snips in questions will try help debug.